# Packet sniffing tools

Tags: networking, packet

OS: Windows XP

Is there any tool that can do packet sniffing by processes? I use Wireshark before, but that's too wide. I need just to look into a certain process.

Comment: For which OS do you want this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en) can display the process for each traffic "stream" captured.

Answer (score 4):

[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) can do this.

If the process doesn't change its ports too often, you can get a list of the process' ports with

```
$ lsof -i | grep <process name>
```

Then use tcpdump.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i en1 port 80 > dump.txt
```

Where en1 is your interface.

```
$ ifconfig
```

to get a list.

$ man -t lsof | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
$ man -t tcpdump | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
$ man -t pcap-filter | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app